# get specific output from terraform rt 53 resolver

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have this output

```
ip_adresses = [
  [
    {
      "ip" = "192.168.1.1"
      "ip_id" = "rni-297efwf83340689"
      "subnet_id" = "subnet-123456789"
    },
    {
      "ip" = "192.168.1.2"
      "ip_id" = "rni-40b04503a"
      "subnet_id" = "subnet-123465798"
    },
  ],
]
```

This is my output statement

```
  description = "Resolver IP addresses"
  value = aws_route53_resolver_endpoint.whatever[*].ip_address.ip

}
```

How do I only get the IP and not everything?

Answer (score 0):

The terraform manual page for output, 'Use in automation' section:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/output.html

> For the common case of directly using a string value in a shell
> script, you can use -raw instead, which will print the string directly
> with no extra escaping or whitespace.

So I think what you are doing is:

```
terraform output aws_route53_resolver_endpoint.whatever[*].ip_address.ip
//outputs:
ip = [192.168.1.1]
```

So the ip text, equals sign and square brackets are unneeded shrapnel.

So if you add the parameter `-raw`, I think thats what you want:

```
terraform output -raw aws_route53_resolver_endpoint.whatever[*].ip_address.ip
//outputs:
192.168.1.1
```

Just the ip, all other stuff gone.